# EditText numberDecimal but keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to use an EditText to only receive decimals, and it work's, but only in android emulator. In my Xiaomi (MIUI optimization disabled), the first time I click on it, normal keyboard appears (but I can't write anything), and the second time, numeric keyboard appears and now I'm able to use it the right way.
 This is the code for the EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_cambio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Any thoughts on what can be happening?
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this line in your Manifest for Activity where you have EditText

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you so much :))) I'm going to read about this because I don't know how it really works.

Comment: Just saw your comment. If you didn't find the explanation, the point is android calls default keyboard  when you click on a TextView but you restrict letter input so you can't type. My solution cancels the default keyboard call and you just get your decimal keyboard